# Compiled LINQ queries in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I've read that in .NET 4.5 and EF5 queries are compiled by default, thus requiring no "work" by the developer to make their linq queries compilable.

If I install .NET 4.5 on my server and target my app to use .net 4.5 will all my Entity Framework queries be compiled and thus receive the increase in performance?

Comment: Make sure the Entity Framework 5 package is installed as well.

Comment: Can an app built in VS2010 target .net 4.5? Or should I just conver that app to VS2012

Comment: You can only target .Net 4.5 in vs2012

Comment: I converted my vs2010 app to 2012, installed entity 5. is there any way I can verify my linq queries are being compiled?

Answer (score 1):

Your queries will be compiled by a background worker and cached. This is part of the query pipeline and cannot be circumvented. So if you are using EF5 on .NET 4.5 your queries will be compiled and cached.